# Cucumber migrate scenario to scenario outline

Tags: java, datatable, cucumber, scenarios

I want to move a multi-row scenario to a scenario outline so that the individual lines of the table can be tested as separate tests. Here's a simplified example of what I have in mind:

```
Scenario: This scenario loops through the lines of the table performing an assert on each line
    When I do something and verify it
      | name         | parameter1 | parameter2   | parameter3 |
      | A and 1      | A          | 1            | true       |
      | B and 1      | B          | 1            | false      |
      | A and 2      | A          | 2            | false      |
      | B and 2      | B          | 2            | true       |
```

The step definition looks like this:

```
@When("I do something and verify it")
public void doSomethingAndVerifyIt(DataTable dataTable) {
    List<Map<String, String>> keyValues = dataTable.asMaps();
    for (Map<String, String> keyValue : keyValues) {
        assertSomething(keyValue.get("parameter1"), keyValue.get("parameter2"), keyValue.get("parameter3"));
    }
}
```

This works fine, but if any of the rows fails the assertion step, then the test stops at this point. I'd like to change this to using a scenario outline along these lines so that the lines can pass or fail independently of each other:

```
Scenario Outline: This scenario loops through the lines of the table performing an assert on each line
    When I do something and verify it

Examples:
      | name         | parameter1 | parameter2  | parameter3 |
      | A and 1      | A          | 1           | true       |
      | B and 1      | B          | 1           | false      |
      | A and 2      | A          | 2           | false      |
      | B and 2      | B          | 2           | true       |
```

How do I change the step definition so that each time, one row is read by the test? I know that I could do this by adding a line under the step definition that explicitly declares each parameter by name, but in my case this would involve a huge number of parameters.

Is there a simpler way to do this along these lines:

```
@When("I do something and verify it")
public void doSomethingAndVerifyIt(Map<String, String> keyValue) {
    assertSomething(keyValue.get("parameter1"), keyValue.get("parameter2"), keyValue.get("parameter3"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my other answer for how to use table.

A better way to improve your scenario is to convert your examples to named rules.
Examples are very useful when capturing information from the business when discussing behaviour. However they are not very good when it comes to writing code. Lets explore this a bit with password login.

Say we have

```
password     | success?

123456       |   no
xb32drthcyfe |   no
p@ssword1    |   yes
```

as our examples. The problem we have here is we don't know WHY `xb32drthcyfe` should fail and `p@ssword1` should succeed. We can guess, but our scenario has failed to record the WHY.

Now consider

```
Scenario: Passwords must contain a symbol
 When I register with a password without a symbol
 Then I should see my password needs a symbol
```

Now you have a single scenario that not only documents the WHY, but allows you to challenge the WHY, and explore the WHY e.g

```
Scenario: Weak password that contains a symbol
 Given my password is long enough has a symbol but it is really weak
 When I register with my password
 Then I should be registered.
```

Now you can present the above behaviour to your business and say, do we really want to do this.

Every example should have a unique named rule behind it. For an example to become mature enough to reside in your cukes you need to reveal this rule, give it a name and then replace the usage of the example in your cukes with scenarios exploring the rule.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There is a big difference between the two ways to run these tests. The first will fail as soon as one assertion fails, and so not all of the rows of the table may be tested.  In the second way, all four tests will run, and their results will be reported irrespective of passes and fails in the other rows. The rules information is interesting, but not really relevant to my question.

Comment: Sorry my bad, you are correct about that. I don't use tables or scenario outlines ever, so forgive me for that error.  The rest of the post still applies. As for getting your scenario outline to work see my second answer. I've edited first answer to remove mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the column headers in your step defs as params so cucumber can replace the params with values in your table e.g

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left |
    |    12 |   5 |    7 |
    |    20 |   5 |   15 |
```

Comment: Yes, I know that including the parameters as explicit parameters in the steps would work, but to be honest, I was hoping to avoid that. I have a lot of parameters and was hoping to just read them in as a Map for each row in the examples table, rather than declaring them separately. It seems like a very natural thing to want to do!

Comment: You can't do that Cucumber would have no way of knowing what to do with them. If you have complex data that you want to program into scenarios you should take my first approach. Putting lots of rows of data in scenarios is a really bad anti-pattern. I understand that programming in features seems like a natural thing to do, but its absolutely contrary to their design and function. Do the work to turn each row of data (each example) into a rule. Not only will it make your scenarios better it will help make you code better if you allow it.